# expo/native build attempt errors just off (basically) boilerplate?

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, jvm, gradlew

I carry all the red-flags of a JS web-developer coming into app-dev land. I have no issue in learning for myself but, I do sometimes need a little nudge of direction/context here since I'm mostly getting slapped down by just trying to implement a little bit of boilerplate. Creating a expo app with `npx create-expo-app`. I dl a couple of libraries (fonts,icons, reanimated) and set up a trivial Loader screen with a little bit of reanimated implemented. Now, running the commands  of `eas build:configure` and then `eas build -p android --profile preview`, I get the Gradle build failed with unknown error. I'm basically getting clipped by this error almost no matter what I do (or little I change to the startup boilerplate) so again, I'm a little frustrated at knowing really where to begin. I get that there is quiiiiiite a bit all going on underneath the hood so, yea, if any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Just trying to get familiar with expo/app-building process so really just trying to run builds on almost untouched boilerplate. I ran the `npx expo-doctor` and updated a couple of expo config/plugins that were apparently outdated but again these all feel like grievances within the initial setup. I wasn't expecting errors from things that seem?? entirely untouched/unbothered by me.

Lastly, the suggestion of running ./gradlew is also a huh to me since expo seems to tuck all that underneath the hood and does not provide an android/ios directories.

**Small update** happens trying to build right after installing `expo install @expo-google-fonts/bangers expo-font expo-app-loading`

Here are the error logs. Again, any suggestions appreciated.

Below is my package.json as well as the error-logs

`{ "name": "myanimatedtimer", "version": "1.0.0", "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js", "scripts": { "start": "expo start", "android": "expo start --android", "ios": "expo start --ios", "web": "expo start --web" }, "dependencies": { "@expo-google-fonts/bangers": "^0.2.3", "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.8.0", "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.7.0", "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0", "expo": "~50.0.8", "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1", "expo-font": "~11.10.3", "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1", "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "0.73.4", "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.2" }, "devDependencies": { "@babel/core": "^7.20.0" }, "private": true }`

`Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
10%
20%.
30%.
40%.
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.3!
Here are the highlights of this release:

- Faster Java compilation
- Reduced memory usage
- Support for running on Java 20
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/release-notes.html
  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
  Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

> Configure project :
> Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393".
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" ready.
> Installing NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" complete.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" finished.
> Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
> 1: Task failed with an exception.

---

- Where:
  Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-splash-screen/android/build.gradle' line: 40
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-splash-screen'.

> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-splash-screen:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> ==============================================================================
> 2: Task failed with an exception.

---

- Where:
  Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 65
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.

> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> ==============================================================================
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 23s
> 5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
> Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
> Fail build

1
1s

Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.`

Comment: Try to switch your JDK from 17 to 20 then `gradle clean` and try again.